# PHP/SQL order by date_time. order by Year not month mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: php, sql, datetime, sql-order-by

I'm having trouble with "order by date_time."  I have a php page that is accessing our db.  I have a function that will display our data in a table. The sql statement is as follows:

```
SELECT date_time
, pass_no
, location2 
from usr_vftcapstone_0.vftPasses as P, Scans as S 
where P.user_name='terak' and S.details2=P.`pass_no` order by S.date_time;
```

I'm doing a "join" so that I can get all the data that relates to a user.
The user has a list of passes.  Those passes have location2.  I'm trying to get all of the "location2" entries from all of the passes assigned to the user.

I have tried:

```
order by convert(datetime, date_time, 103) ASC

style 103 = dd/MM/yyyy (msdn)
```

for this, I don't know where to include "style 103."  I tried it after "ASC" in the same sql statement, but I dont think that is how it works.

My output is ordering in decending order, but it is ordering by the month.  I need it to order by the year.
The date_time field displays like this: `1/01/2013 10:30:51`

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just order by the date_time field.  Only convert to a string for display purposes.

Comment: I think that it is saved as a string. or varChar.  There is a 'datetime' data-type, yeah?  And sometimes its stored as such in your db?

Comment: When I order by datetime, it uses the month, not the year. mm/dd/yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date_time, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s')
```

Style numbers are for SQL Server, but your query looks like MySQL.

If your dates can be in different formats (what kind of screwed up database is this?), you can do something like:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN date_time LIKE '%/%/% %:%:%'
                   THEN STR_TO_DATE(date_time, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s')
              WHEN date_time LIKE '%/%/% %:%'
                   THEN STR_TO_DATE(date_time, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')
         END
```

Comment: Damn just missed by a minute :)

Comment: I like the look of this.  seems like it should work. But its still displaying in a crazy order.

Comment: I like the look of this.  seems like it should work, but its not.  Still displaying in a crazy order.  Now looking at my output.  some of my datetime has mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm  and some has mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS it looks like it is taking 4/14/2013 HH:MM and goes to 3/24/13 then 2/23/13 and then once it gets to 1/18/2013 it is displaying the different dateTime HHMMSS, but it is still going to december 2013 after january 2013 (because of the 1 vs 12) still sorting by month, it looks like.  

What do you mean style numbers and do I need to manage %d %m etc?

Comment: @TerakRaines Can you check with my solution below

Comment: @Yogus Sorry I didn't get back until now.  I was working on other finals stuff as well.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your June 3 comment until now. See my updated answer for how to deal with varying formats of the date_time column. Also, make sure these formats actually match what's in your DB. Your question said it's day/month/year, not month/day/year.

Comment: I assume you can fix the format string yourself. If not, find yourself another line of work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this

```
SELECT date_time
, pass_no
, location2 
from usr_vftcapstone_0.vftPasses as P, Scans as S 
where P.user_name='terak' and S.details2=P.`pass_no` 
order by SUBSTRING(S.date_time,7,4) ASC
```

I have used it from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)

```
SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )
```

Also try this

I have used Use [DATEPART (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms174420.aspx) to extract year.

```
 SELECT date_time
    , pass_no
    , location2 
    from usr_vftcapstone_0.vftPasses as P, Scans as S 
    where P.user_name='terak' and S.details2=P.`pass_no` order by 
datePart(yy, convert(datetime, S.date_time, 103)) ASC
```

Comment: I tried using the datePart section in my sqlEditor.  It sent me an error.  And I'm unsure why.  is 'datetime' the correct dataType?  And what does th 103 refer to?